# Detecting significant changes in behaviors

Tags: statistics

I am working on a problem that requires me to determine significant change in the behavior of users. But I do not have the idea of how it can be accomplished. The scenario is as follows:

I am analyzing users posting classified ads. The goal is to determine if there is a significant change in behavior of user over time as regards to the categories in which the ads are frequently posted. For example, suppose during week 1, 75% of the user ads were in category A but only 60% during week 2, then I would like to detect this sharp change. However, the caveat is that the raw numbers behind the percentages could have been extremely low (for example 3/4 in week 1 and 3/5 in week 2) in which case, the change is not so sharp as the 15% difference suggests.

I would like to determine such significant changes over time for a user. How can I go about achieving it? Any ideas/thoughts are welcome.

Comment: You can use $\chi^2$ tests and others to detect significanvce. However, almost all statistical tests require sample sizes of at least $5$ to make any sense at all. Hence your very small sample with 3 out of 4 versus 3 out of 5 change cannot be called significant.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_detection ?